# JavaScript: Retry wrapper for the fetch-API

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know there are many good libraries for this, but to understand the issue better, here is my own basic attempt.

The fetch will be retried if it fails with a promise rejection or the response indicates a server error.

It assumes that GET, PUT, etc. are idempotent, like they should be.

```
function retryWrapper (fun, delay, getTryCount, retryOn) {
  /*
     fun - function to retry, async function
    
     delay - delay between retries in ms
    
     getTryCount - function to calculate number of tries, 
                   determined by arguments to fun
                   returns number of max retries
    
     retryOn - function to check if result should be retried
               returns false if should be retried
   */
  return async function (...args) {
    const count = getTryCount(...args)
    let i = 0
    let result = null
    while (i < count) {
      try {
        result = await fun(...args)
        if (retryOn(result)) {
          return result
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e)
        if (i === count - 1) {
          // if no more retries left, throw the error
          throw e
        }
      }
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay))
      i++
      delay *= 2
    }
    return result
  }
}

function retryOn (res) {
  if (res.status >= 500 && res.status < 600) {
    // in case of server error we should retry
    return false
  }

  return true
  // in case of success or client error it makes no sense to retry
}

function getTryCount (...args) {
  const tryCount = 5
  if (args.length <= 1) {
    // no options, the method is GET
    return tryCount
  }
  const options = args[1]
  if (['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE'].includes(options.method)) {
    // idempotent methods
    return tryCount
  }
  return 1 // PATCH, non-idempotent methods like POST, etc.
}

export default retryWrapper(fetch, 100, getTryCount, retryOn)
```